# Apache Ranger is Failed to install in Kerberos Hadoop cluster

Tags: kerberos, ambari, apache-ranger

I have enabled Kerberos from Ambari 2.7.2 and tested authentication from Kafka and HBase.Now  I have tried to install Apache Ranger for Authorization. using Mysql DB in Unix based. ranger admin is installed but ranger user-sync is not installing. I am getting below error in Ambari UI.

```
RuntimeError: Failed to execute command '/usr/bin/apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef --allow-unauthenticated --assume-yes install ranger-3-1-0-0-78-admin', exited with code '100', message: 'E: Failed to fetch http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/ubuntu16/3.x/updates/3.1.0.0/pool/main/r/ranger/ranger-3-1-0-0-78-admin_1.2.0.3.1.0.0-78_all.deb  403  Forbidden
```

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

In Ambari audit logs I am getting below error

```
2019-07-15T12:19:54.906+0530, User(admin), Operation(CUSTOM_COMMAND RANGER_USERSYNC), Details(RESTART RANGER/RANGER_USERSYNC), Status(ABORTED), RequestId(205), TaskId(969), Hostname(HOSTNAME)
2019-07-15T12:20:28.121+0530, User(admin), RemoteIp(192.168.14.203), Operation(INSTALLED: RANGER_USERSYNC/RANGER on HOSTNAME (TrinityHub)), Host name(HOSTNAME), RequestId(206), Status(Successfully queued)
2019-07-15T12:20:28.128+0530, User(admin), Operation(Install Ranger Usersync), Status(IN_PROGRESS), RequestId(206)
2019-07-15T12:20:28.128+0530, User(admin), Operation(INSTALL RANGER_USERSYNC), Status(QUEUED), RequestId(206), TaskId(970), Hostname(HOSTNAME)
2019-07-15T12:21:09.870+0530, User(admin), Operation(Install Ranger Usersync), Status(FAILED), RequestId(206)
2019-07-15T12:21:09.870+0530, User(admin), Operation(INSTALL RANGER_USERSYNC), Status(FAILED), RequestId(206), TaskId(970), Hostname(HOSTNAME)
2019-07-15T12:21:10.339+0530, User(admin), Operation(EXECUTE AMBARI_SERVER_ACTION), Details(Preparing Operations), Status(ABORTED), RequestId(206), TaskId(971), Hostname(null)
2019-07-15T12:21:10.339+0530, User(admin), Operation(CUSTOM_COMMAND KERBEROS_CLIENT), Details(CHECK_KEYTABS KERBEROS/KERBEROS_CLIENT), Status(ABORTED), RequestId(206), TaskId(972), Hostname(HOSTNAME)
```

Comment: You asked the same question 3 times, do you really think that makes a difference?

Comment: NO all are same it was by mistake